# Generating Camera Motion

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, motion-capture

I'm a beginner at blender. I want to create camera motion in videos with a stationary camera. Things like translating the camera arbitrarily through the scene etc. Can someone please give me a detailed explanation on how I can do so?

Comment: What does "with a stationary camera" mean? If you're moving the camera, it won't be stationary.

Comment: Or if you mean editing a live-action video with a stationary camera, to have camera motion, I'm afraid that's impossible—the video doesn't include anything outside the frame, which you would need as soon as you moved the camera.

Comment: Hi! what I meant was that I have a video with a stationary camera. Now, i want to generate camera motion in that video using blender. Will that be possible? I'm considering 360 videos.

Comment: If it's a live-action video, then unfortunately it is not possible. The video doesn't include any information you can't see, like what's behind other objects—which you would need if you tried to move the camera. You would also need stuff outside the original frame, which isn't recorded in the original video. Now, if the _original video_ is of a CGI scene, then yes—but you'd have to talk to the person who made the video and see if they could give you the scene itself. The 2D video just won't work.

Comment: Although if the video is a 360º one, and you just want to rotate around your camera position _without moving_, you could do that.

Comment: oh, i got your point. Thanks a lot for the help! I really appreciate it.